# How to get Processed string from string in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

In my application I have used core data for data persistent.

I have one entity "Networks"

Networks entity have one attribute ip  address.

Many times ip address is not in well format . Can I transform one raw ip string to other well  form string i.e can I process core data entity  attribute value using heavy core data migration like custom  Entity Migration Policies .

When to go for Custom Entity Migration Policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is a migration necessary? The easiest answer to this common question is “when you need to make changes to the data model.”

You need to opt for Custom Entity Migration only when you have changed the entity type of your attribute.

You can get more information about this topic in here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/174025/lightweight-migrations-in-core-data-tutorial

Comment: So in my case I just want to process  raw or non standard format to standard correct format..should I convert NSString to  transformable type or do some other

Comment: You can do that without migrating. You can probably write a parser which does the transformation whenever needed. If I am not wrong you will be getting the ip addresses from an API. So what you can do is, get the ip address, give it to the parser which transforms the data to proper string format and store it in core data.